# Laravel swagger api-docs json file not found

Tags: php, laravel, swagger

I am trying to add swagger into my laravel project.

installed

```
composer require "darkaonline/l5-swagger:5.6.*"
```

so when i do

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/documentation
```

got info

```
Fetch error Not Found http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs/api-docs.json
```

already created docs folder with that json file.

Should i adjust route or change swagger base URL somewhere?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should run the command

```
php artisan l5-swagger:generate
```

after adding the annotations

Comment: php artisan l5-swagger:generate is not working  5.8.18

Answer (score 3):

And if you are still getting the `Not Found http://your-host/docs/api-docs.json` error, run

```
chown www-data storage -R
```

Answer (score 1):

if you still get "Not Found" error after running the command:

```
php artisan l5-swagger:generate
```

run

```
php artisan route:cache
```

worked for me